# Google Sheets + Apps Script: create datalist only if column from sheet contain matches word from getElementById('item1')

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi I've got this code that works great to create a datalist by looking at my google sheet and create a datalist if column 'G' match the word specified in var spec = 'specific word'; what I'm trying to do
is instead of using a preset word in the variable spec I would need the variable spec to get its value from the element called 'item1' so I've tried replacing  var spec = 'specific word' with var specWord = document.getElementById('item1').value;. I've tried all kinds of ways but just can't seem to get it working I always get a ReferenceError: specWord is not defined
here's the code I'm using now

```
                <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
    
                   <div class="form-row">

                      <div class="form-group col-md-4"  align="center">
                        <label for="item1">Item / Equipment</label>
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="item1" name="item1">
                      </div>
                     
                     <div class="form-group col-md-2" align="center">
                       <script type='text/javascript'>
                        function unitUpdate() {
                         var names = document.getElementById("unit1").value
                          var nameArr = names.split(',');
                          document.getElementById("unit1").value = nameArr[0];
                          }
                       </script>
                      <label for="unitTruck">Unit #</label>
                        <input type="text" id="unit1" class="form-control" list="unitTruck" name="unitTruck" onchange="unitUpdate()">
                       <datalist id="unitTruck"  >
                          <?
                        var sheet   = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Over All Rate");


                        var specWord = "Truck"; //  I NEED spec variable TO BE REPLACE BY Element item1 value 
                        

                        var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
                            var myRange = sheet.getRange("E2:G"+lastRow);
                            var data = myRange.getValues().filter(function([,,g]) {return g.indexOf(specWord ) > -1})
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) { ?>
                              <option value="<?!= data[i] ?>">
                               <? } ?>
                          </datalist>
                        </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Modification points:

- When the templated HTML is used, the filtered values of scriptlets are loaded, when the HTML is loaded like `HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index").evaluate()`. And in your script, there are not script for retrieving the search values from the text input. In your case, it is required to set the filtered values by inputting the search value, after the HTML was loaded. For this, I would like to suggest the following 2 patterns.

1. All values are retrieved using the scriptlets when the HTML is loaded, and the values are filtered by the retrieved search value and put to the text input.
2. Filtered values are retrieved using `google.script.run` after the HTML was loaded.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, all values are retrieved using the scriptlets when the HTML is loaded, and the values are filtered by the retrieved search value and put to the text input. In this case, the script of HTML&Javascript side is modified.

#### Modified script:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4"  align="center">
  <label for="item1">Item / Equipment</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="item1" name="item1">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-2" align="center">
  <label for="unitTruck">Unit #</label>
  <input type="text" id="unit1" class="form-control" list="unitTruck" name="unitTruck" onchange="unitUpdate()">
  <datalist id="unitTruck"></datalist>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function unitUpdate() {
  var names = document.getElementById("unit1").value
  var nameArr = names.split(',');
  document.getElementById("unit1").value = nameArr[0];
}

// I modified below script.
<?
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Over All Rate");
var data = sheet.getRange("E2:G" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
?>
var values = JSON.parse(<?= JSON.stringify(data) ?>);

document.getElementById("item1").addEventListener("change", e => {
  var v = values.filter(function([,,g]) {return g.indexOf(e.srcElement.value) > -1});
  var el = document.getElementById("unitTruck");
  while (el.firstChild) el.removeChild(el.firstChild);
  v.forEach(val => {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.setAttribute("value", val);
    el.appendChild(option);
  })
});
</script>
```

- When above modified script is used, when the HTML is loaded, all values are retrieved from the Spreadsheet, and the retrieved values are used for filtering.
- For example, if the Spreadsheet is updated during the HTML is using, the updated values are not used. Because all values are loaded when the HTML is loaded. But the response speed will be a bit faster than that of pattern 2.
- When you want to run the script during the value is inputting, please modify `addEventListener("change", (e) => {` to `addEventListener("input", (e) => {`.

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the filtered values are retrieved using `google.script.run` when the search value is inputted, after the HTML was loaded. In this case, the script uses both HTML&Javascript side and Google Apps Script side.

#### HTML & Javascript side: `index.html`

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4"  align="center">
  <label for="item1">Item / Equipment</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="item1" name="item1">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-2" align="center">
  <label for="unitTruck">Unit #</label>
  <input type="text" id="unit1" class="form-control" list="unitTruck" name="unitTruck" onchange="unitUpdate()">
  <datalist id="unitTruck"></datalist>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function unitUpdate() {
  var names = document.getElementById("unit1").value
  var nameArr = names.split(',');
  document.getElementById("unit1").value = nameArr[0];
}

// I added below script.
document.getElementById("item1").addEventListener("change", e => {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(v => {
    var el = document.getElementById("unitTruck");
    while (el.firstChild) el.removeChild(el.firstChild);
    v.forEach(val => {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.setAttribute("value", val);
      el.appendChild(option);
    })
  }).getValues(e.srcElement.value);
});
</script>
```

#### Google Apps Script side: `Code.gs`

```
function getValues(specWord) {
  var sheet   = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Over All Rate");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var myRange = sheet.getRange("E2:G"+lastRow);
  var data = myRange.getValues().filter(function([,,g]) {return g.indexOf(specWord ) > -1});
  return data;
}
```

- When the same function name of `getValues` is included in your GAS project, please rename it. Please be careful this.
- When above modified script is used, after the HTML was loaded, when you put a value to "Item / Equipment" and the forcus is moved from the text input to others, the script is run and you can see the filtered values at "Unit #". In this modified script, when the value is put to "Item / Equipment", the values of "Unit #" is updated every time.
- For example, if the Spreadsheet is updated during the HTML is using, the updated values can be used. Because the values are retrieved every time when the search value is inputted. But the response speed will be a bit lower than that of pattern 1.

### Note:

- When you want to run the script during the value is inputting, please modify `addEventListener("change", (e) => {` to `addEventListener("input", (e) => {`.

### Reference:

- [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)